# rewrite the domain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, dns

I was trying to simplify the domain for the sake of SEO. 
I want to change http://www.abc.com/index.cfm/ID/48/Home  to http://www.abc.com/home
I tried the code below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}^/index.cfm/ID/48/Home/ ?$  
RewriteCond %{Query_string}^$  
RewriteRule^(.*)/home [L,QSA]
```

I am not an IT person but have to do this. Can anybody help me to see if I write correctly? If it is wrong, how to do to meet my goal? So appreciate for your help in advance!

Comment: What is the current state of things and what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this alone for the single page rewrite.

```
RewriteRule  index\.cfm/ID/48/Home http://www.abc.com/home [L,QSA]
```

If you want http://www.abc.com/home to be the URL but to show the other use this:

```
RewriteRule  home /index.cfm/ID/48/Home [PT,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Ray! I sent the code below to another company to do it for us. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}^/home/ ?$  
RewriteCond %{Query_string}^$  
RewriteRule^(.*)/index.cfm/ID/48/Home/ [L,QSA]                            It turned out to be if you click both links, it would goes to the same page. However, I wanted replace http://www.abc.com/home with http:www.abc.com/index.cfm/ID/48/Home. I will try yours and see if it works. Thanks so much!!!